Is $\mathcal H/\Gamma$ defined over a number field when $\Gamma$ is not congruent?
Let $\mathcal H$ denote the upper half plane of complex numbers, and $\Gamma$ an arithmetic subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z )$ (not necessarily congruent). I wonder whether $\mathcal H/\Gamma$ (as an algebraic variety) can still be defined over a number field? I'm not familiar with the theory of reflex field, and I only know this is true if $\Gamma$ is congruent.

You can regard this as a corollary of Belyi's theorem.

To convert my comment to an answer: Let $X=\mathbb H^2$ denote the hyperbolic plane and $\Gamma< \Lambda=PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$ a finite-index subgroup. I will treat $X/\Gamma, X/\Lambda$ as Riemann surfaces, ignoring (at first) the orbifold structure. Then the natural projection $f: X/\Gamma\to X/\Lambda$ is a holomorphic map. I identify $X/\Lambda$ with the complex line $\mathbb C$, so that the orbifold points (now, I treat $X/\Lambda$ as an orbifold) are $0$ and $1$. The map $f$ extends to a holomorphic map $F$ of projective completions of these Riemann surfaces, $F: S\to \mathbb C P^1=\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\}$. The map $F$ has three critical values: $0, 1, \infty$. Hence, by Belyi's Theorem, $S$ is biholomorphic to a projective curve defined over $\bar {\mathbb Q}$, as requested.
